# Text-wrapping JLabels with no preferred/max/min size

Tags: java, swing, text, jlabel, word-wrap

I'm using JLabels as hyperlinks. I want them to look and function exactly like a link in a browser, so using text panes/editor panes etc is not desirable. The problem is that many of the containers these links will be placed in do not have a size specified: they rely on the size of their parents (or even grand-parents).

I am using Boxes for layouts, and if the link text spans more than about two-thirds the width of the box, the box contents begin to stretch outside the actual bounds of the box (so that, if that box were surrounded by a JScrollPane, a horizontal scrollbar would appear).

Is there any way to enforce wrapping on a JLabel? Many posts I have read say that putting the text in HTML tags will cause it to wrap automatically when necessary - but no matter what I do I cannot get this to work. I can't use `<br />` tags because I do not know exactly where they would go unless this could be automated, i.e.:

```
if(text.length() > wrapLength)
{
    //break the text into substrings and insert a <br /> at wrapLength
    //the difficulty is in figuring out the value of wrapLength
}
```

Here is the code for the hyperlink class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Hyperlink extends JLabel
{
    private URI uri;
    private String baseText;

    public Hyperlink(String text, String uri, Font font, Color textColor)
    {
        super(text);
        baseText = text;
        setFont(font);
        setForeground(textColor);
        setOpaque(false);

        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
        {
            try
            {
                setToolTipText(uri);
                this.uri = new URI(uri);
                addMouseListener(new LinkMouseListener());
            }
            catch(URISyntaxException ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private class LinkMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try
            {
                desktop.browse(uri);
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong..."); //DELETE
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
            setText("<html><u>" + baseText + "</u></html>");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
            setText(baseText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the label, try `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height))`, `setSize(new Dimension(width, height))` or `setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height))` and set the width to the width where you want it to wrap. I think in your case it will be setMaximumSize(...).

It doesn't wrap automatically because of your layout manager. Some layout managers will ignore the preferred size or other dimensions. In your case, you probably just need to play around with the different setXXXSize() methods and find the one that is respected by your layout manager.

To get the preferred width, you're going to have to get the width from one of the parents. Once again, depending on the layout manager, you might have to get the preferred width, maximum width or getSize().getWidth(). Without knowing more about the layout, it's difficult to say how exactly you need to do this, but you do need to set some kind of width on the label for it to wrap - There's no way around that.

The only other option I can think of would be to set the preferred width on the label to something arbitrary that you know should always fit in the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JTextArea. The text can be set to wrap automatically. You can play with the text area properties to make it look like a label.

You can use a custom Highlighter to "underline" the text. Then you just add/remove the highlighter as necessary. The [Rectangle Painter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) can get you started.